# Adsense 5.1 Errors and Out-Of-Band Signal using CookiePro

Tags: json, adsense, cookieconsent, iab

I am getting a lot of 5.1 errors in the Adsense dashboard for my site. I've talked with the CMP which is OneTrust (Using CookiePro solution).

They told me the following:

"At OneTrust, we do not support OOB (Out-Of-Band signal)."

"You'll see that OOB  is empty. We include the empty array in the getTCData call, but don't populate it. Your Google ad sense may read it, see it's empty and then ignore it. You will need to make this setting on your side.

Also, I recommend you contacting Google on this as to why you are getting 5.1 error."

[image]

The arrays inside are empty for allowedVendors and discloedVencors, still, Google gives 5.1 errors.

Is there any way I need to change on my side to make it work?

Thank you.